# Pandas dataframe : TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= datetime.date()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a .csv into a pandas dataframe (CorpActionsDf).  the head of which is:

```
                       date  factor_value reference             factor
unique_id                                                             
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  24/04/2015          0.70    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  25/04/2014          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  26/04/2013          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  26/11/2012          9.18      None  Return of Capital
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  27/04/2012          0.46    Annual       Regular Cash
```

I am then trying to filter the dataframe so I only keep the data between two dates.

```
startDate=02-01-2008
endDate=20-02-2008
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2008-01-02
```

I have another process that uses the startDate and endDate to filter information with sucess but for some reason this time I can't get the filtering to work.  My code is as follows:

```
def getCorpActionsData(rawStaticDataPath,startDate,endDate):
    pattern = 'CorporateActions'+ '.csv'
    staticPath = rawStaticDataPath
    
    with open(staticPath+pattern,'rt') as f:
      
         CorpActionsDf = pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=None,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],parse_dates=[1], 
                                     dayfirst=True,index_col=[1],names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])       
         print(CorpActionsDf.head())
       
         CorpActionsDf = CorpActionsDf[(CorpActionsDf.index >= startDate) & (CorpActionsDf.index <= endDate)]
```

I set parse_dates equal to column 1 so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: pd.read_csv can take a file or filelike-object. Why are you opening the file yourself?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

i guess your index is of string (object) type - because of that the following condition `(CorpActionsDf.index >= startDate)` gives you `str() >= datetime.date()` error message.

what does `CorpActionsDf.index.dtype` give as an output?

**OLD answer:**

make sure that your `startDate` and `endDate` have correct data type:

```
startDate=pd.to_datetime('02-01-2008')
endDate=pd.to_datetime('20-02-2008')
```

Comment: yep, set the start and end date to pd.to_datetime, unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: @Stacey, what is the output of `CorpActionsDf.index.dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try first convert `strings` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use indexing by this values:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S,24/04/2015,0.70,Annual,Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S,25/04/2014,0.61,Annual,Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S,26/04/2013,0.53,Annual,Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S,26/11/2012,9.18,None,Return of Capital
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S,27/04/2012,0.46,Annual,Regular Cash
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
CorpActionsDf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 header=None,
                 usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],
                 parse_dates=[1],
                 dayfirst=True,
                 index_col=[1],
                 names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])
print CorpActionsDf
                  unique_id  factor_value reference             factor
date                                                                  
2015-04-24  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.70    Annual       Regular Cash
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
2012-04-27  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.46    Annual       Regular Cash    
startDate=pd.to_datetime('2014-04-25')
endDate=pd.to_datetime('2012-11-26')

print CorpActionsDf[startDate:endDate]
                  unique_id  factor_value reference             factor
date                                                                  
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
```

Interesting, if use `strings`, last row is omited:

```
print CorpActionsDf['2014-04-25':'2012-11-26']
                  unique_id  factor_value reference        factor
date                                                             
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual  Regular Cash
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual  Regular Cash
```

EDIT:

You have to [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for correct selecting:

```
print CorpActionsDf
                  unique_id  factor_value reference             factor
date                                                                  
2015-04-24  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.70    Annual       Regular Cash
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
2012-04-27  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.46    Annual       Regular Cash

CorpActionsDf = CorpActionsDf.sort_index()
print CorpActionsDf

date                                                                  
2012-04-27  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.46    Annual       Regular Cash
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
2015-04-24  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.70    Annual       Regular Cash

print CorpActionsDf['2012-11-2':'2014-04-25']
                  unique_id  factor_value reference             factor
date                                                                  
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
```

Another solution with [`truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
print CorpActionsDf.truncate(before='2012-11-2', after='2014-04-25')
                  unique_id  factor_value reference             factor
date                                                                  
2012-11-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          9.18      None  Return of Capital
2013-04-26  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
2014-04-25  BBG.XAMS.ASML.S          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
```

Comment: thanks, i tried CorpActionsDf = pd.read_csv(f, 
                 header=None,
                 usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],
                 parse_dates=[1],
                 dayfirst=True,
                 index_col=[1],
                 names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])   but got the following error: 'KeyError: 'Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: datetime.date(2008, 1, 2)'', any idea what I need to do?

Comment: It means there is no `datetime.date(2008, 1, 2)` in index. So you have to use: `CorpActionsDf = CorpActionsDf[(CorpActionsDf.index >= startDate) & (CorpActionsDf.index <= endDate)]`

Comment: Hi jezrael, tried the change to the code now get an error 'TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2008-01-02'

Comment: Hmmm, I test all solutions and it seems only sorting of index is necessary. I think you can try copy creating my dataframe and try test it. For me it works very well. Btw, I use pandas `0.18.0`.